# Java HashMap put() strange behaviour

Tags: java, hashmap, put

I have created a `HashMap` with ten fields: the `key` type is `String` and the `value` type is an `double[]`.

When I try to update the map using `put(String id, double[] newVal)`, not only the value associated to the "id" key is updated, but all values in the map.

How to resolve this issue?

```
      for (int j = 0;j<attrIndex.length;j ++){

        String name = train.attribute(attrIndex [j]).name();
        double g = eval.evaluateAttribute(attrIndex[j]);

        double[] newVal = {0.0, 0.0};
        double w = 1;
        if (g == 0.0) 
            w = 0.5;

        newVal = table.get(name);
        newVal[0] += g;
        newVal[1] += w;
        table.put(name, newVal);

    }
```

Comment: I'm sure you are putting the reference to the same array for all the keys. Well, this is the answer, but it would be better if you could show the code of how you put elements into the Map.

Comment: you are probably using always the same array. show us some code

Comment: Are you using the same key by accident for each entry?

Comment: How about some lines of code?

Comment: Here the code. I tried to debug it and i saw that during the first iteration the put() function updated all the values in the map.

Comment: The bug comes from elsewhere; the place where you populate the map with the initial arrays. And you probably populate it with always the same array as value. Show the code which populates the map initially, before the above code is executed.

Comment: The solution you posted before works!! Thank you! But can you explain me why? I mean why if i modify just a value of a key the function put() modifies the values associated to each key??

Comment: Now i' ve read carefully your comment and you are right: I populated the map with same array. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the real bug is not in the code you have shown us.  Consider this:

```
    double[] newVal = {0.0, 0.0};
    // ...
    newVal = table.get(name);   // LOOK HERE
    newVal[0] += g;
    newVal[1] += w;
    table.put(name, newVal);
```

At first glance, it looks like you are creating a new `double[]` and then updating it.  But in fact, the `double[]` that is getting updated is the one that you are pulling from the hash table.  (The `double[]` you are initializing is getting thrown away, and the `put` operation in your code is redundant.)

So how can this be a problem?  Well, *by itself* it isn't.  But it does mean that *something else* must be populating `table` with an initial set of entries.  And the symptoms would suggest that the code that populates the table looks something like this:

```
   double[] val = {0.0, 0.0};
   for (String name : ...) {
       table.put(name, val);
   }
```

... which is creating multiple hash table entries *that all share the same `double[]`*.  So naturally, when you update the values associated with one name, you are actually updating the values associated with all of the names.

---

The reason that JB Nizet's (now deleted) code fixed the problem is that it was replacing the `double[]` object each time it updated an entry.

But a better way to fix this is to change the initialization code to this:

```
   for (String name : ...) {
       double[] val = {0.0, 0.0};
       table.put(name, val);
   }
```

And you can simplify your update code to this:

```
for (int j = 0;j<attrIndex.length;j ++){
    String name = train.attribute(attrIndex [j]).name();
    double g = eval.evaluateAttribute(attrIndex[j]);
    double w = 1;
    if (g == 0.0) 
        w = 0.5;
    double[] val = table.get(name);
    val[0] += g;
    val[1] += w;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same array in each iteration of the loop.
Change

```
double[] newVal = {0.0, 0.0};
```

to

```
double[] newVal = new double[]{0.0, 0.0};
```

Comment: Isn't the first one just a shorthand for the second form?

Comment: Thank for the help, but as i have already said, the problem shows up during the first iteration. Besides, i tried to do as you say and it doesn'y work.

Comment: I can't believe four people have actually thought it's the right answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You only create a single double[], so all key/value pair share the same values.

Try creating a new array:

```
table.put(name, new double[]{newVal[0], newVal[1]);
```

Just a quick hack, there are certainly more elegant solutions.